# Как UI элемент привязать к спрайту

Tags: unity3d

Есть к примеру хелсбар в канвасе, который динамически создается, есть спрайт юнита. Собственно как преобразовать этот хелсбар(scale, position), что бы он отобразился на спрайте(сверху, ну с офсетом я разберусь) c преобразованным скейлом и позицией?

Comment: [world space canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно преобразовать мировую позицию с объекта сцены, в локальную позицию канваса.
https://answers.unity.com/questions/799616/unity-46-beta-19-how-to-convert-from-world-space-t.html